# How to add menu items to the Communities menu in IBM Connections?

Tags: ibm-connections, ibm-sbt

I wish to add a new menu item/link (e.g. "Stack Overflow") at the end of the menu in the screenshot below.

The new link URL would end in the `community_uuid` e.g. `http://example.stackoverflow.com/some-page#community_uuid`

Is there any good documentation available to show how this is done?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Immediately I thought of three things:

1 - Custom CSS for a community, so you could somehow add/change or maybe create a landing spot for a dom manipulation event which adds it.
In order to change the CSS, You should look at:
http://infolib.lotus.com/resources/oneui/3.0/docPublic/components/menu.htm 
It's the navbar role.

In a folder such as /local/con/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/installedApps/conServerCell/Communities.ear/comm.web.war/nav/common/styles/orangeTheme/

2 - 
You may also want to look at /local/con/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/config/cells/conServerCell/LotusConnections-config/widgets-config.xml

specifically

you could add a StackOverflow widget, when loaded it automatically opens up a new window, and transfers the person back to the previous page. ... a little bit of a kluge...

3 - Look for /local/con/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/installedApps/conServerCell/Communities.ear/comm.web.war/nav/templates/page.jsp

find the line 
`<div class="lotusMenu" id="lotusMenu" style="display:none;" role="navigation" aria-label="Main navigation"><div class="lotusBottomCorner"><div class="lotusInner">
                                        <div id="lotusMenuTree"></div>
                                        </div></div></div>`

You could modify the very end to add some custom link for you.

Just some quick thoughts...